# Routes in express JS

Tags: node.js, express

I have a code line:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

for static files in public folder, but build a route:

```
app.get('/search/jobs', jobs.index);
```

The Expressjs is putting `/search` before `url`.

And I'm a getting error in console browser:

GET: http://localhost:5000/search/css/materialize.css

Any idea?

Comment: what is the error saying, is it saying 404 http://localhost:5000/search/css/materialize.css not found

Comment: yes, error not load static files..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use absolute paths in your html/css (e.g. `/css/materialize.css`). With relative paths (e.g. `css/materialize.css`) the browser will look up the path relative to the current path/"directory" (`/search` in this case).